# attributes and configurable products

Tags: attributes

I have an attribute set, men's apparel and I have added to attributes;
color and size.

When I go to add a product, I select the mens apparel attribute set and configurable product. Then i get a screen with 2 checkboxes, color and size.

If I check both boxes and select continue, neither shows up. If i go back and check the color box only and click on continue, the size box only shows up. and the opposite is true. any help would be sincerely appreciated.

both items are set to global and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes"

Comment: They should be set to apply to simple products. The 'children' of the configurable. Is that how they are? Then once you've created the configurable parent and saved , you can auto-generate under associated products, there should be the two drop down options for color and size

Answer (score 1):

When creating a configurable product you specify the attributes on which it is configured (i.e. color and size in your case). Means you will associate simple products using this attribute.

So if you select both the check-boxes (color and size) for creating the configurable product it means the associated products (i.e. simple products) will have this attribute value specified with them.
Hence you will find the option for specifying the attribute value (i.e. color and size in your case) when you create the associated products (simple products).

Now, if you select only one attribute while creating the configurable product (ie color) you can configure the associated products (i.e. simple products) using color only. 
The other attribute (i.e. size) will be available with the configurable product, as you don't want to create the associated products (i.e. simple products) using this attribute (i.e. size).

The opposite is also true for size and color.